# Recommended way to construct quaternion from roll/pitch/yaw with tf2?

Tags: ros, transforms, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the recommended way to construct a quaternion from roll/pitch/yaw with tf2?

The [tf2 wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Quaternions) gives this code:

```
tf::Quaternion q = tf::createQuaternionFromRPY(0, 0, 0);
```

Unfortunately tf itself is deprecated and I'm looking for a pure tf2 solution. I can't find the `createQuaternionFromRPY` function in tf2, although the [migration guide](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Migration) says it is a superset of tf. Am I missing something?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/304397/recommended-way-to-construct-quaternion-from-roll/pitch/yaw-with-tf2?/) by [bluenote](https://answers.ros.org/users/37779/bluenote/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2018-09-27

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes the `createQuaternionFromRPY` constructor is deprecated. But you can do it using two lines with the `setRPY` method:

```
float roll = 0;
float pitch = 0;
float yaw = 0;

tf2::Quaternion myQuaternion;
myQuaternion.setRPY( roll, pitch, yaw );
```

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bluenote](https://answers.ros.org/users/37779/bluenote/) on 2018-09-28**:
Okay than my understand of "superset" is different. Not so nice that there is no longer a single expression (e.g. when I want a const quaternion).

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-09-28**:
I agree, I've put this change in my own code too. It's not as elegant but it's supported.

**Comment by [IanCol](https://answers.ros.org/users/26764/iancol/) on 2020-03-19**:
Anyone know why it's deprecated? it's a nice one-line way to create a quaternion.